# feel — or to have been taught

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive

I saw the following sentence in a book, and I don't know why the "to" is there.
Is it correct at all?

> Most people feel — or **to** have been taught — that there is an
> absolute difference between “creative writing” and “the other kind”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the "to" looks out of place, and is probably an error.

The implied "or" is "Most people to have been taught that...".  That is clearly wrong.

An interesting observation is that it took me multiple attempts to understand the question. I did not see the word "to" at all at first.  My brain just edited out of the sentence.

Comment: Can we, by any chance, take it this way: *most people feel to have been taught...*?

Comment: It can't be read that way.  It is just about possible that this was the intention, but it is hugely more likely that it is a simple mistake.

Comment: @MaulikV Can the verb "feel" take an infinitive? I'm not talking about an infinitive as in "It feels good to be young again," where the infinitival phrase is actually the real subject that the "it" refers to.

Comment: @Apollyon though rare, it won't be *incorrect.* [Longman Dictionary has an entry](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Longman_Dictionary_of_Contemporary_Engli/CrQtkEgG0SAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22feel+to%22&pg=PA630&printsec=frontcover) - *feel ...to be/do something...* I think *to have been...* takes care of grammar there.

Comment: @MaulikV The entry you mentioned is exactly the type I am NOT talking about. That entry illustrates that the infinitival phrase is the real subject.

Comment: I doubt you could find examples with a human subject followed by "feel to V."

Comment: Could be many *I **feel to speak out*** but not now! :)

Comment: That sounds like Indian English.

Comment: Could you make a sentence using a human subject followed by "feel to V"?